# Apache Multiple hosts on one server - different ports

Tags: apache-2.2

I have configured apache to listen on Port 80 & 8080 and have created 2 conf files for the sites.

**Port 80**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /local/Web

    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
     Alias /access /local/Web/

    <Directory "/local/Web">
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI

      DirectoryIndex index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

access to 127.0.0.1 loads the correct site from /local/Web

**Port 8080**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 DocumentRoot /local/Sites

    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
        Alias /site1 /local/Sites/site1/
        Alias /site2 /local/Sites/site2/
        Alias /site3 /local/Sites/site3/

    <Directory "/local/Sites">
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI

      DirectoryIndex index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

accessing 127.0.0.1:8080 brings up Access Denied which is fine

accessing 127.0.0.1:8080/site1 loads the correct site from /local/Sites/site1

accessing 127.0.0.1:8080/site2 loads the correct site from /local/Sites/site2

accessing 127.0.0.1:8080/site3 loads the correct site from /local/Sites/site3

I can't access site1, site2, site3 from port 80 and I can't access /access from port 8080 - which is all as expected.

I'm now trying to add a new site to Port 80 using a new conf file.
I want this to have it's own conf file as :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /local/Web

    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
    Alias /new /local/new

    <Directory "/local/Web">
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI

      DirectoryIndex index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Yet when I try any access 127.0.0.1/new I get 'Object not found!' and nothing is shown in the apache error_log

Any idea how I get /new to work on port 80 ?

Comment: Why don't you add a new alias to your existing `<VirtualHost *:80>` config file?

Comment: The sites are from two different applications. So I may have one config file, the other or both...

Answer (score 1):

Apache does not know which config for VirtualHost *:80 should use. You have two ways how to fix it:

1. Merge those two configs into one virtualhost
2. Use ServerName and "hostname" URL for determining which VirtualHost should be used.

Comment: Thanks - can server name be 127.0.0.1/new ?

Comment: Nope, server name must be "hostname" ie. new-localhost. You have to modify your hosts to map new-localhost to your server with apache